# cv::ogl::mapGLBuffer reports error CL_INVALID_CONTEXT

Tags: opencv, opengl, opencl

I would like to utilize OpenCV's integration of OpenGL/OpenCL to achieve fast distortion of images directly on the GPU while avoiding GPU/CPU image transfers. I can create a `cv::ogl::Buffer` from an OpenGL buffer object in Qt:

```
// m_pub is of type QOpenGLBuffer
cv::ogl::Buffer b(512, 512, CV_8UC4, m_pub.bufferId());
```

But the next line throws an exception:

```
cv::UMat m = cv::ogl::mapGLBuffer(b);
```

The error reported by OpenCV was originally:

> OpenCV(4.5.5) Error: Unknown error code -220 (OpenCL:
> clCreateFromGLBuffer failed) in cv::ogl::mapGLBuffer, file
> D:\OpenCV\opencv-4.5.5\modules\core\src\opengl.cpp, line 1886

To get further information, I call `cv::ocl::getOpenCLErrorString(status);` in opengl.cpp, rebuild, and find that the error is CL_INVALID_CONTEXT.

I've checked `cv::ocl::Context`, `cv::ocl::Device`, `cv::ocl::Platform`, added `cv::ocl::attachContext`, all doesn't work. I'm stuck here, don't know how to go forward.
Any suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't see tutorials in the docs, just the API documentation. do the samples help? https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.x/samples/opengl specifically https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/17234f82d025e3bbfbf611089637e5aa2038e7b8/samples/opengl/opengl_interop.cpp#L373

Comment: Thank you very much, the two samples are very helpful. The latter one uses `cv::UMat`, `cv::ogl::mapGLBuffer()` and `cv::ogl::convertFromGLTexture2D()`, it can run normally. I've solved the problem in my program and post a answer below. @ChristophRackwitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to call `cv::ogl::ocl::initializeContextFromGL()` in the initialization phase. My project is based on Qt, the window is inherited from QOpenGLWindow, so I call that function in `initializeGL()`.

I guess that without this call, OpenCV would also create an OpenCL context automatically, but that's not the same as the one created from OpenGL, that's why the **CL_INVALID_CONTEXT** error occurred.

As a reminder, I used `cv::remap` to process a 512x512 image and found that processing on the GPU via OpenCL was not much faster than on the CPU. It still takes around 12ms on average. This is still too slow if the application requires a high frame rate and needs to leave time for other processing.

Comment: GPU programming's biggest pitfall is underestimating latency from data transfers and other "spinup" costs. GPUs only really shine when they can stream/pipeline data into kernels. it may be possible to improve the situation by using a GPU profiler. -- and if you don't need custom kernels, simply use `cv::UMat`, which makes data live on the GPU. that allows basic OpenCV functions (not in ocl or anywhere) to engage OpenCL transparently.